# How can I allow a group to execute a command as another user?

Tags: sudo, group

I'm conservative about my `sudoers` policy. I'm trying to allow `wheel` users to run `psql postgres postgres` as the `postgres` user (because when ident that's the only way it works).

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=/usr/bin/psql
```

here's the error

```
 Sorry, user xenoterracide is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/psql postgres postgres' as postgres on slave-vi.
```

The command I'm running is

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres postgres
```

The policy works for executing things as `root`, but I just need this specific command to run as `postgres`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%wheel ALL = (postgres) /usr/bin/psql
```